# lightgallery UPDATE INDEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, lightbox

With the filter option (uikit), we can put img mosaic in `display:none`, but how can we `update` the lightbox `index` from `lightgallery.js` plugin please?

JS :

```
var $lg = $('.js-filter');
$lg.lightGallery({thumbnail: false});

// $lg.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);  ???
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/o5ahdnzb/2/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could hook to the uikit filter event, to destoy and trigger a new gallery:

```js
// Gallery container
var $lg = $('.js-filter');

// Initialize the gallery for all the elements
$lg.lightGallery({
  selector: 'li',
  thumbnail: false
});

// After uikit filter is applied
$('[uk-filter]').on('afterFilter', function() {

  // Destoy the previously created gallery
  $lg.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);

  // Initialize new gallery with just the visible items
  $lg.lightGallery({
    selector: 'li:visible',
    thumbnail: false
  });

});
```